# How can I get a track search on the basis of title - SoundCloud?

Tags: javascript, soundcloud

Basically I want to Stream audio on the basis of song title search.

The search results are vague and meaningless :

```
SC.initialize({
  client_id: "MY_ID",
});


SC.get('/tracks', { title:'welcome to the black parade'}, function(tracks) {
  console.log(tracks);
});
```

But the results are way too different from the actual song.But the results on the web-site are good.

So I can't search any song randomly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `q` instead of `title`

`SC.get('/tracks', { q:'welcome to the black parade'}, function(tracks) {
  console.log(tracks);
});`